# Fetch Multiple Rows From Sybase Cursor

Tags: cursor, sybase, sap-ase

(Sybase ASE) I'm trying to fetch multiple rows from a cursor into something usable. So far I've managed to successfully fetch in batches of 1000:

```
DECLARE indexBlockCursor CURSOR
FOR SELECT DISTINCT indexId 
FROM #HighestPriorityIdTypeCode
FOR READ ONLY

SET CURSOR ROWS 1000 for indexBlockCursor

open indexBlockCursor

fetch from indexBlockCursor
```

This prints the first 1000, when I run it, however I want to be able to manipulate these rows. When I try:

```
fetch from indexBlockCursor into #sometable
```

I get a syntax error and when i fetch into a variable I only get one row.

```
fetch from indexBlockCursor into @somevariable
```

Please tell me how I can get the rows out of the cursor into something I can manipulate. E.g

```
fetch from indexBlockCursor into [something]
select * from [something]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is not possible fetch with SET CURSOR ROWS 1000 will just act as proc that selects something inside. 
Solution here would be:

1. create #sometable,
2. fetch 1000 times row by row in while loop and insert to #sometable,
3. do whatever you want with #sometable.